# How to determine treasure for characters who aren't materialistic?

Tags: dnd-5e, treasure, star-wars

I am putting together a campaign for my daughters - late high school / early college age - using the [SW5e](https://www.reddit.com/r/sw5e/) ruleset. Effectively, this is a total conversion of the standard D&D 5e rules into the Star Wars universe.

My daughters are most drawn to the classes that fall under the Jedi archetypes. As such, in the Star Wars universe there are not a lot of obvious rewards that make sense. At this point I expect there to be no non-Jedi characters in the party.

- They would not (necessarily) claim treasure found in the course of an adventure
- Even if they claimed loot, they wouldn't have an in-universe use for it: Their basic needs for clothing, weapons, even transport, are provided by the Jedi Order. For example, most Jedi use their lightsaber almost exclusively, and it's the same saber they've had since they were younglings.

How can I provide treasure that is impactful to them without having them sacrifice their altruistic ideals? I want them to feel like they're getting something without making them feel like they are doing something that isn't in line with their character design.

Comment: At the moment, this feel very broad - but that's okay. Would you say that your ultimate goal (which isn't necessarily tied to Star Wars or even 5e) is in how to provide treasure for those not interested in or needing a lot of material possessions?

Comment: @NautArch Pretty much exactly that, yes. It's possible that this is also addressed in the older Star Wars RPG books, which I have not read. But the general case is that the characters' equipment and needs are provided for them and therefore don't come directly from in-game rewards.

Comment: I made a pretty big edit - do you agree with it? Also, I removed your ideas because they're an answer and not necessarily part of your question. You absolutely can submit your own answer as them or just wait and see how the community responds for direction.

Comment: Just a note here to answerers: SW5e appears to be a complete hack of 5e for a Star Wars universe. They have their own PHB which you can find in the link in the post and possibly their own rules and mechanics. If you answer please be sure that your answer applies to this exact system and not just generic D&D5e.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose On the other hand, they do *not* have a DMG, and I do have the 5th edition books. (both PHB and DMG)

Comment: @GalacticCowboy: Yup! I just wanted to make sure answerers were aware that there may be differences and that they need to be familiar with those if they are going to answer. Good question and I hope you and your daughters have a stellar time :)

Comment: @T.E.D. Not that they wouldn't find them exciting or useful, but that the flavor of Jedi in the Star Wars universe doesn't lend itself to "You find 300 gold pieces and a suit of armor lying in the corner. You take it."

Comment: @GalacticCowboy - I could see that point wrt to the "gold pieces" (but honestly SW money is probably all going to be electronic credits anyway, so that probably shouldn't happen much). But finding better robes, shielding, or a super-well built light saber once used by a famous master, all that seems like it ought to be A Thing.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

### Non Treasure Rewards

The 5e DMG (Chapter 7) has [a substantial section about rewards other than treasure](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/dmg/other-rewards). Examples include Blessings of various kinds, meaningful and magical Charms handed to the characters, very powerful Boons, and (most relevantly) various Marks of Prestige.

Marks of Prestige will probably be your most common rewards.

- Letters of Recommendation, and other personalized introductions, can give the characters easier access to information, immediate resources, emergency aid, and interesting NPCs that the Order is unable to provide, or unable to provide **in time**.
- Medals are formal acknowledgements of courage and success, that can provide in-story benefits when dealing with NPCs.
- Parcels of Land, Special Rights, and Titles are excellent ways for local governments to reward planet-hopping adventurers; lots of prestige and nominal rewards but little practical cost to the government.
- Strongholds are similar to parcels of land, but expected to be used for military purposes.
- Training is a reward that can grant lots of cool abilities.

Good luck!

Comment: I edited out your link to dandwiki as that is not a legitimate republication of WoTC material and linked instead to the dndbeyond's DMG.

Comment: @NautArch That link is useless to people, like myself, that do not (and cannot) have a D&D Beyond account.

Comment: And that's why I also added the chapter in the DMG. But we can't provide links to copyright violations.

Comment: The linked section is indeed nowhere in the SRD and not covered by the OGL, so it looks like someone added it illicitly. I'm going to see if I can contact dandwiki about it somehow. Expect the page to be taken down, and links to it to die in the near future, probably.

Comment: @doppelspooker Indeed, there are apparently a number of sites now, claiming to host the 5e SRD, but which contain content not in the actual [SRD](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/systems-reference-document-srd).

Comment: I like these Marks of Prestige. Their first set of encounters will be on behalf of a prominent senator (not Palpatine! :) ) so that may be a reasonable reward.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I think this one is closest to what I had in mind, but I'll definitely keep the others in mind as well.

Answer (score 10):

## Use immaterial rewards

If your players can't or won't take "stuff" as a reward, then rewards them for their adventures in other ways. Having a local crime lord owe the players a favor, making prominent connections in a royal court, earning private training in specific skills from a powerful character, or unlocking some hidden potential within the character are all things that could benefit a party without material acquisitions. The 5e DMG (Chapter 7) provides [a list of potential rewards for players beyond treasure](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/dmg/other-rewards#Blessings).

Comment: I edited out your link to dandwiki as that is not a legitimate republication of WoTC material and linked instead to the dndbeyond's DMG.

Comment: @NautArch -- unfortunately the dndbeyond link is inaccessible without paying.

Comment: @ravery True, but the same content is also inaccessible without paying for the book - and those are the only two legitimate sources for it. Linking to [pirated content](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2773/1204) is something we simply can't do.

Comment: @ravery see [this meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7669/stance-on-using-dd-beyond-for-references) for our policy on DnDBeyond links.

Comment: @doppelspooker what value does moving the link between words add?

Comment: @NautArch -- dndwiki is pirated?

Comment: @ravery no, the site is not pirated. But that particular content from chapter 7 of the DMG someone posted to it is. Doppelspooker has notified dandwiki.

Comment: @NautArch: Seems it's been deleted from dandwiki now.

Answer (score 8):

I like [inthemanual's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/133194/how-to-determine-treasure-for-characters-who-arent-materialistic/133196#133196) but sometimes the only thing you can get is money.

## Give it to charity

Just because Jedi don't need money does not mean there aren't people who need it. You could give them a bonuses based on how much they give away. That might make for some interesting conflicts of interest.

Should we push on the rich noble we helped to give more money to help the poor?

How about the moderately rich? They don't need it. Think of the poor Rodian children!

## Give it to the Temple

I bet that those fancy light-sabers and robes don't come cheap. And food, and electricity.

Same thing as above with the belief that you should financially support the people who clothed, trained, and fed you. This could also give bonuses like the ones inthemanual's.

You could even have a leader board with the Jedis who gave the most... Well maybe not leader boards but maybe more respect to the ones who give the more.

## Upgrade Gear

Sure they have the base equipment but it can always be better... and exponentially more expensive. Think about how many people you could save with some better armor or better murder sticks.

How about owning a nice, fast, expensive ship to go to places faster to do more good. Or a speeder to get to places on the ground faster to save the bothan from the house fire.

This is all for the good of the people, of course but the truth is that players love bigger numbers.

Just remember to increase the numbers of the enemies to keep things tense.

## It's like the force... But better!

Oh no! The alien guarding the drug house is immune to jedi mind tricks. With no other way in we will have to brutishly decapitate him to get in... Or maybe pay him off.

You failed the roll to convince the secretary of the corrupt governor to hand over the incriminating files. Stabbing time? 
Or maybe just pay them off.

You want to get the mercilessness mercenary to leave the poor farmer alone. Murder hobo time?
Or just pay them off.

Think of money like the force but it works with a MUCH higher chance of success.

Comment: This is very similar to the answer I would have posted (only mine wouldn't have been as good).  The only thing I would add is that the best way to motivate players to donate money to charity is probably to introduce them to NPCs that demonstrate a need.  The Jedi defeated the notorious crime boss?  What happens to the slaves that criminal captured?  They may have family waiting for them on the other end of an expensive space trip, or maybe they have nothing, and nowhere to go. What about that informant who gave you the passcode? They're living on the streets, struggling for food.

Comment: @Beofett great points.

Answer (score 6):

### Money Can Be Exchanged For Goods *and Services*

A Jedi has very little in the way of material needs, both because of their lack of attachment and their organization's resources. Sure, some Jedi characters might save up for some items (a top of the line ship, perhaps), but others would have no particular interest in material things outside of their starting equipment. But that doesn't mean they have no use for money: far from it. Because although they don't have a need for or interest in money, they often need to interact with people who do.

### Contacts and Information (Knowledge and Defense)

A Jedi has great insight into many matters through their connection to the Force: but they can't know everything or be everywhere. **Sometimes, the ability to employ people to search for something or give them information could be useful**. And if the desired information can only be found within wretched hives of scum and villainy, then a Jedi's noble demeanor might make them ill-suited to such an investigation.

At times like this, credits could be very useful. You let it be known that you are offering a reward for information about a certain subject or person. Or you could go to a contact you trust and pay them for secrets they trade in. Sometimes, money could be used to acquire literally priceless artifacts: you could put out a reward for information that could lead you to an ancient Jedi Holocron, for example (which you couldn't buy, but might be able to find through a network of well paid informants).

**You might even need the money to hire someone with a certain skill set:** can the Force hack a computer, or forge a document? If not, then you may need to use those credits to employ an expert. Especially if you hope for this expert to become a long time contact, or a reliable source.

### Mind Tricks Don't Work on Me. Only Money

The Force can have a strong influence on the weak minded, but sometimes that's not the best option. **There may often be unsavory on downright despicable people you need to deal with whose only interest is money:** and having it can make a big difference. From freeing slaves to forgiving a smuggler's debt to bribing a corrupt warlord, money can be a path to righteous deeds when all other options are blocked.

While a Jedi may usually hope to appeal to either their authority, might, or use of the Force to encourage cooperation, these may fall on deaf (or immune) ears. At times like those, the universal message of currency can be very useful.

### Wars not make one great

Jedi are martial masters, capable of defeating most foes they can approach. **But what if the goal is to build, not to break?** What if they encounter a town in need of a school building, or a settlement that needs upgrades to their moisture condensers, or a colony being ravaged by a plague requiring an expensive cure. A jedi may not need much for themselves, but they could acquire money to see to the needs of others. Although most of your adventures will involve foes to defeat, you might encounter some challenges that simply require you to have the resources sufficient to give to those in need.

At the end of the day, money will still have a lot of uses even to characters who don't care about it. Even when you don't need any to buy any *things*, that doesn't mean you'll never need to buy *anything*. Whether it's the rewarding the services of contacts, employing expert allies, appeasing the corrupt, or aiding the needy, money can always have a use to a Jedi.

Answer (score 3):

Lots of good answers already, but if you are willing to invest the time upfront I think that plot flexibility might be an attractive reward. If the plot is strong enough, and their effects on it foreseeable enough, then you can dole out plot changes as "loot".

Jedi may not get into the business to make money but they do care about things. If your in-game universe is well-stocked with characters and factions that have understandable goals and reasonable plans to accomplish those goals then the outcome of a mission (or campaign, or however you want to structure the narrative) can be the "reward"-- a galaxy that better fits what your players think it should be.

This can be especially effective if the goals of various factions brings them into conflict with one another as the results of missions will be more visible (because for one group to advance towards its goals others must drift further away from their own). So for especially altruistic characters their rewards might include a fairer galaxy and better, more fulfilling lives for its inhabitants or a reduced ability for some villainous military organization to cause trouble.

You can make this as loose or rigid as you want. Sticking to the general loot tables can instead give you some sort of abstracted "plot token", where you convert the typical rewards into progress towards an appropriately dramatic setting change. Or you can decide on changes on-the-fly without worrying about that much detail. **As long as the character progression suggested by D&D-style loot is compensated for or made unnecessary in some way, treasure and loot shift closer to flavor than mechanics.**

Answer (score 3):

I too would recommend the content in chapter 7 of the 5e DMG, but also **don't stop giving them normal loot**. Even Jedi can get greedy at times and a greedy Jedi turning to the dark side could make for an interesting plot hook. Allowing them to loot credits/treasure off the bodies will let them have a chance at corruption.

Comment: And watch for alignment shifts, the Dark Side needs bodies as well.

Comment: If you simply want to add on to other answers, you should comment on them instead. As written, this answer doesn't exactly answer the question asked. I'd suggest expanding it to address the question directly, perhaps by summarizing the main suggestions you'd give the asker about how to make treasure impactful.

Comment: I'd argue its not "greedy" to be happy with better gear so that you can accomplish harder missions for people.

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver re: alignment shifts - the game includes an optional module with mechanisms for going to the dark side, and possible short- or long-term effects of doing so.

Answer (score 2):

### Give Them Responsibility

Their reward could be an assignment to a planetary governorship. Find a planet near the Outer Rim that needs protection or law instilled. Their reward is more responsibility and a chance to make a difference in the universe! This might turn the campaign a bit more diplomacy based, but there are always ruffians, smugglers, and lawless types on the fringes of society to deal with, as well as great beasts to protect their citizenry from. Consider placing a resource that the Empire would covet on this planet and your villains naturally will start showing up.

Answer (score 2):

Why not give them material rewards?  Jedi love cool new lightsaber crystals that give them new colors or different damage factors, or the ability to change blade lengths.

How about a holocron, or a datapad with a clue to the location of a holocron?  Incredible new Jedi powers await!  Or any number of jumping off points for other adventures.

Perhaps someone's been working on a new, flexible ablative armor that can be worn under Jedi robes?

Answer (score 1):

For someone who is not materialistic, the greatest treasure is often friendship.

Drawing from the films as well as expanded universe content, Jedi frequently rely upon friends they have made in previous adventures to help them in future ones. Characters like Maz Kanata, Dexter Jettster, and Lando are great examples from the movies of NPCs who could become recurring helpers to the party.

Along with the other good suggestions made so far, I think its worth emphasizing this point that making connections, or seeing people's lives improved from their efforts should be the main reward for completing missions as a traditional Jedi.

I find it helpful to read novels, such as the "Jedi Apprentice" series for inspiration.

Comment: Great point about the books. The Star Wars universe is very well documented. :)

Answer (score -2):

### New Force Powers

Most loot only goes to increased rolls but you can still give them those increases without the loot. I suggest you give your players new "force powers" when they complete a goal. These can range from combat, to utilitarian in nature and can take a basis from the show.

I would take the numbers from similar 5e spells so they don't break the game but that is up to you. Some simple ideas are

- force lightning (or upgrade to chained force lightning)
- upgrade force push to be a cone at will
- jedi mind tricks that work better
- force enhanced strength/dexterity/constitution
- stopping force use by others

(I have never played SW5e, only 5e and enjoy SW)

Comment: That may be pretty overpowered. In 5e, handing out new spells/abilities is not standard treasure. The closest would be a magic item equivalent to a scroll or something you can cast with - but those are generally limited and not part of your total spells/abilities.